# convert dtype from object to float

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`df = pd.read_csv('C:/data/graduate-employment-survey.csv', sep=',', encoding='latin-1')`

I want to convert the dtype from object to float but I encounter a error, it says "could not convert string to float: 'na'". In my file there are 'na' value in it , so how do i solve this if
`df['employment_rate_overall'] = df['employment_rate_overall'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)` cant be used to convert?

[image]

I tried doing this and I managed to change the 'na' value to 0.

```
df['employment_rate_overall'] = df['employment_rate_overall'].str.replace('na', '0').astype(float)
```

but how do i remove the row with 'na' or '0' values? i tried dropna() but it doesnt work.

Comment: You need to fill-in `na` values with some default float value like 0 or something depending on the business domain. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Comment: It would be helpful for us to reduced example of your data frame so that we can see what your data looks like.

Comment: `str.remove("")` might help?

Comment: I have added some data from the file

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
pd.to_numeric(df['employment_rate_overall'], errors='coerce')
```

Demo:

```
values = ['1', '2.3', np.nan, 'a', '4', '5.6', 'na']
pd.to_numeric(values, errors='coerce')
```

Output:

```
array([1. , 2.3, nan, nan, 4. , 5.6, nan])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the code is literally trying to convert the string `"na"` to a float, which is not going to happen.  If `"na"` is the only non-numeric element you can just do:

`df = df.replace("na", None)`

and do your conversion to float after that